# 'I need you!' 'So do I' Is this grammatical?

Tags: conversation

> Evelyn: I need you!
>   Sam: So do I!

Is this grammatical? What is the meaning of the response?

Comment: Yes. *Need* can be not only a modal, but also a common verb.

Answer (score 2):

That conversation is perfectly grammatical. *So do I* shows an agreement with what the previous person said. In this case, the conversation would be equivalent to:

> Evelyn: I need you!
>   Sam: I need you too!

It would be overly pedantic indeed to infer that the second person is saying *I need myself too*.